# Java: Error handling with error variable detection

Tags: java

I am currently creating a small application that gets RGB values from the user in some JTextFields and is required to change the colour of the text that is printed in the middle of the JFrame. I need to be able to tell if the user inserts a non integer value in one of the JTextFields to throw an error message and delete the wrong input from the JTextField and keep the right values in the other JTextFields.

```
public class App extends JFrame {
    public JTextField txtR, txtG, txtB;
    private JButton reset, set;
    private JPanel northPane, centrePane, southPane;
    public JLabel mainText;
    public Color colour;

    public App() {
        northPane = new JPanel();
        northPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        centrePane = new JPanel();
        centrePane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        southPane = new JPanel();

        txtR = new JTextField(3);
        txtG = new JTextField(3);
        txtB = new JTextField(3);

        set = new JButton("Set");
        set.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        mainText = new JLabel("CE203 Assignment 1, submitted by: 1704074");
        colour = new Color(0,0,255);
        mainText.setForeground(colour);

        northPane.add(reset);

        centrePane.add(mainText);

        southPane.add(txtR);
        southPane.add(txtG);
        southPane.add(txtB);
        southPane.add(set);

        add(northPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centrePane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(southPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(400,400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App frame = new App();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the button handler

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    private App theApp;
    private int valueR, valueG, valueB;

    ButtonHandler( App app ) {
        theApp = app;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            valueR = Integer.parseInt(theApp.txtR.getText());
            valueG = Integer.parseInt(theApp.txtG.getText());
            valueB = Integer.parseInt(theApp.txtB.getText());
            theApp.colour = new Color(valueR, valueG, valueB);
            theApp.mainText.setForeground(theApp.colour);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter integer values in the fields ","Wrong input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code what I think I need is just an if for each JTextField in the catch block but I don't know what to use.

Comment: Please post the code for your `app` class too (and note that by Java coding conventions it should be capitalised as `App`).

Comment: I added the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. As you noted, the problem is that you're using the same `catch` statement to handle all three text fields without being able to identify which one is problematic.

A quick (if somewhat inelegant) solution is to use parallel arrays to iterate over the text boxes and set each value accordingly:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JTextField[] fields = {theApp.txtR, theApp.txtG, theApp.txtB};
    int[] colourValues = new int[3];
    int i = 0;
    boolean error = false;
    for (JTextField field : fields) {
        try {
            colourValues[i++] = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            error = true;
            field.setText("");
        }
    }
    if (!error) {
        theApp.colour = new Color(colourValues[0], colourValues[1], colourValues[2]);
        theApp.mainText.setForeground(theApp.colour);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter integer values in the fields ","Wrong input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid parallel arrays, another option would be to use the `Color(int rgb)` constructor instead, and in each iteration of the loop set the appropriate component.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JTextField[] fields = {theApp.txtR, theApp.txtG, theApp.txtB};
    int rgb = 0, i = 0;
    boolean error = false;
    for (JTextField field : fields) {
        try {
            rgb |= (Integer.parseInt(field.getText())) << (16 - i);
            i += 8;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            error = true;
            field.setText("");
        }
    }
    if (!error) {
        theApp.colour = new Color(rgb);
        theApp.mainText.setForeground(theApp.colour);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter integer values in the fields ","Wrong input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Note also that, after having validated that each value is an integer, you'll also want to validate that they're between 0 and 255.